# How to change the color of explorer items of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

As this screenshot shows, vscode has multiple sections that I can click, But because of my color scheme, I can hardly see which one I'm selecting right now.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPF5W.png)

I already know that using settings like

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.focusBackground": "#571863",
    "list.inactiveFocusBackground": "#56186393",
}
```

can change the background color of the focused `file` or `directory`(shown as picture2).

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9t4u.png)

But those settings can't change the background color of selected sections.

And I also want to know how to switch between those sections (e.g. in this picture, `OUTLINE`, `TIMELINE`, `JAVAPROJECTS`) using the keyboard only.

Thanks in advance.~~~~~

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your `settings.json`.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "sideBar.foreground": "#9A9A9A"
}
```

Source:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#side-bar